# What does the value in standard deviation means?

Tags: standard-deviation

My data is consisted of the scores of high school students in algebra. N=23, the mean is 7.96 and the standard deviation is 4.017. I don't know what does the value of standard deviation tells about my data. Is my data dispersed or not?

Answer (score 0):

Standard deviation is representative of the variation in the data. How much the data points are dispersed around the mean is measured by standard deviation. You can plot histogram of the data points to visualize it.

Comment: what does 4.017 means?